# Unable to change Tab's label Text of VC++ CMFCOutlookBar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

Its been a while i have stopped working on VC++ and now i have some project which i have again started my development on VC++.... I am having a strange issue right now the label of the control is not getting change at all here is my code for initialization of mfcoutlookbar

```
BOOL CMainFrame::CreateOutlookBar(CMFCOutlookBar& bar, UINT uiID, CMFCShellTreeCtrl& tree, CCalendarBar& calendar,CListCtrlBar &listctrl,int nInitialWidth)
{
    bar.SetMode2003();

    BOOL bNameValid;
    CString strTemp;
    bNameValid = strTemp.LoadString(IDS_SHORTCUTS);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    if (!bar.Create(strTemp, this, CRect(0, 0, nInitialWidth, 32000), uiID, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_LEFT))
    {
        return FALSE; // fail to create
    }

    CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl* pOutlookBar = (CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl*)bar.GetUnderlyingWindow();

    if (pOutlookBar == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    pOutlookBar->EnableInPlaceEdit(FALSE); //we dont want editing

    static UINT uiPageID = 1;

    // can float, can autohide, can resize, CAN NOT CLOSE
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_CBRS_FLOAT | AFX_CBRS_AUTOHIDE | AFX_CBRS_RESIZE;

    CRect rectDummy(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const DWORD dwTreeStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS;

    //Create tree
    tree.Create(dwTreeStyle, rectDummy, &bar, 1200);
    //bNameValid = strTemp.LoadString(IDS_FOLDERS);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    pOutlookBar->AddControl(&tree, L"Folders", 2, TRUE, dwStyle);

    //create calender

    calendar.Create(rectDummy, &bar, 1201);
//  bNameValid = strTemp.LoadString(IDS_CALENDAR);
//  ASSERT(bNameValid);
    pOutlookBar->AddControl(&calendar, L"CALLLLLL",1, TRUE, dwStyle);

    //create list control bar
    listctrl.Create(rectDummy,&bar,1202);
//  bNameValid = strTemp.LoadString(IDS_DASHBOARD);//Dashboard to check the statistics and statical reports
//  ASSERT(bNameValid);
    pOutlookBar->AddControl(&listctrl, L"Some", 0, TRUE, dwStyle); //the digit represent icon 

    bar.SetPaneStyle(bar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);

    pOutlookBar->SetImageList(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDB_PAGES_HC : IDB_PAGES, 24);
    pOutlookBar->SetToolbarImageList(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDB_PAGES_SMALL_HC : IDB_PAGES_SMALL, 16);
    pOutlookBar->RecalcLayout();

    BOOL bAnimation = theApp.GetInt(_T("OutlookAnimation"), TRUE);
    CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl::EnableAnimation(bAnimation);

    bar.SetButtonsFont(&afxGlobalData.fontBold);

    return TRUE;
}
```

if you see i am using two different controls by providing them the text label e,,g,

```
pOutlookBar->AddControl(&listctrl, L"Some", 0, TRUE, dwStyle);
```

and the other is

```
pOutlookBar->AddControl(&calendar, L"CALLLLLL",1, TRUE, dwStyle);
```

now the label "Some" and "CALLLLLL" is not being displayed i have tried everything but i dont know why its still displaying the default text of

"Calenders" and "Folders"

I have changed all the text inside String table as well ...this code is generated by Visual Studio C++ by wizard using Office 2000.

What is the mistake i am doing???

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay finally figured out the problem is the cache , the outlookbased bar for any application save the caption and label in registry...so cleaning your solution rebuilding it again and again will not give you the right tabs captions unless you delete the registry entries for that application.

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3153867254-3211561466-2840709754-1000\Software\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications\test2

and then delete this test2 project key ....after that run your application it will display the  correct label.